# How to display the search results of a search term with its sentence in UITableView

Tags: search, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have A HUGE amounts of text in core data and have used a searchbar in my tableView (which shows the texts),and implemented a search in entities with fetchedResultsController and NSpredicate.

so the UITableView shows the **text results** that contains the search term. but I want to display the sentence which contains the *search term* OR 2-3 words before or after the search term.

for instance if I have a text like: "I have a wide knowledge of flying model airplane and loved in CoreData" and search "flying" I want only to display "...wide knowledge of **flying** model airplane..."

how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You wil have to display it in bold?

If no, the answer is as following

- first get the range of the text that has been searched, for example let say you were searching for "word" in sentence "this is the word am searching"
  search for the range of "word" that is 12, and save it in a variable
  then get the a substring with the range from 12 - 10 (range [2,10]) and save it in another variable
  lastly get a sbustring of 10 characters after the word for range [12+4,10] and save it into another variable

now concatenate all these variables (before + " " + "word" + " " + after) and display it

In case you need to make the word bold, then you could use some library like "OHAttributedLabel"  read more https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel

Comment: is there any API for doing this task?

Comment: What do you mean by api?
but no, its mostly normal objective c code, i did something like this in the past, and i dont remember that i used any special api
only rangeOfString